# RTMP Red5 persistent SharedObject with "multiple changes"

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, red5, rtmp

Currently i am working on one app, which use red5 sharedObject for notifying same app, running on other computers about item changes (add/update, remove, lock for editting, etc..).Then application requests outdated data from server (or just remove it). 
SharedObject contains: itemType, dispatcherId, flag(type of change).
 
Everything works as charm, but in case of connection loss, reconnected application will get only last "version" of shared object (in case SO is persistent).
At the moment i do not use any Red5 server side methods, i use SOSample red5 applicaton.
So is any ideas how to store multiple changes is SO?
Looks like `SyncEvent.changeList` holds only one object with oldValue :(

Comment: You can store any data in your shared object that you want. So why not store the history of changes as an Array in the shared object? For clients that need only the most recent change, they get the first (or last) element from the array. Clients that want the entire history, use the entire array...

Comment: I was thinking about this. I think that i have to create server side function to generate some kind of auto incrementing changeId in objects and push them into array, then clients will see what they missed. Thank You.